# Browser storage IndexedDB can be used for storing static files like css and some js file?

Tags: offline, offline-browsing

I want to made offline first web application.

If a network is not available then data and css files should be load from indexedDB.

I may be wrong or this requirement look like weird but want to know that is it possible or not?

I don't want to go with service worker and app cache options.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are  gonna need service worker  to make offline first web application.
You can use indexdb instead of cache.